# BMW 2008 328i Sedan iDrive GPS Navi LCD display - how to connect video RCA to it

Tags: bmw

Does anyone know how to connect a video RCA to the BMW iDrive LCD display? I opened it up and saw this 12-pin connector but there's no RCA hookups anywhere. I wanted to connect a rear view camera to it.

I looked on eBay and people are selling these BMW Multimedia Video Input kits for like $260-$340 and that's too expensive for me.

Is there any cable harness that I can buy cheaply that can hook up to the LCD video screen or any other suggestions?

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You might have to experiment with the connection.  I couldn't find any diagrams describing the pin-out of the iDrive.  Looking for something cheap means you'll likely be hacking something that works yourself.

Comment: This is the only thing I found... maybe it's just not do-able. I might just install a new LCD mirror and connect video to that instead. http://navtv.com/product/41/bmw56-can.html?forceShowProduct=1